# Confusion regarding the role of the capacitor in the electrical equivalent of a membrane

Tags: human-biology, physiology, neurophysiology, electrophysiology

I am having trouble understanding the electrical equivalent of a cell mebrane as it is shown in this picture taken from Kandel:
[image]
What I cannot understand is the capacitor in the specific image. Why is it set parallel to the resistances and what does it symbolize? Does it symbolize all the charges that are accumulated in the cell border? What does the derivative of its charge $\frac{dq}{dt}$ that is shown in the relation $C=\frac{q}{V}$ mean? From my point of view the capacitor symbolizes the two sides of the membrane and so the derivative mentioned above should be equal to the total current through the membrane. However this is my personal opinion that I have not confirmed and which contradicts the electrical equivalent given above. Can someone give me some help?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Right now the answer to your question would be a chapter in a neurophysiology textbook (seems like you should have one in Kandel). What does it teach you?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have the  Jessell, Thomas M.; Schwartz, James H Principles of Neural Science. My problem is not related to what the book sais but to the physical  interpretation of all these membrane properties.

Comment: Okay; I think if I am understanding your questions correctly the first and last have already been answered here, and your middle question isn't really about biology but just physics and what capacitance means. Have you searched for these answers? If you can't find one, then still please ask individual questions supported by what you know about each.

Comment: @BryanKrause I edited my question in order to refer to a single topic. I cannot understand however what do you mean that the first and last questions have been answered. I don't see any answers.

Comment: Did you use the search to look for existing posts on the site? That's where you would find answers.